# egl surface attribute not implemented?

Tags: android, egl

My app was working properly but suddenly it's showing this error:

`Egl surface attribute not implemented.`

Its not even an error, I think. Everything is working properly and I am receiving data properly from local host but its not displayed. 
I tried changing emulator, created new emulator but no use.

[Source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hlduafd209azz7y/Galleries.txt)

Comment: I wonder how come no has answered me. No one ever faced this problem Egl surface attribute not implemented

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore this logcat warning. It shouldn't have any meaningful impact on your app, the emulator just doesn't implement this API.